# In Spring Data JPA , when do you declare a method vs when do you directly use a method without declaring?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring data JPA and I have this question :

I have seen in some places where a method is directly referred without actually being declared in the Repository interface and in some places you have to declare the method before using it.

When is each of them applicable?

Comment: When you create your repository you extend Spring Data's `CrudRepository` (or similar) interface that in turn already consists of some methods out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method is already declared in JpaRepository and is a General method like `findById()` then you should use it directly. 
But if the method contains table names or entities specific to your project like `findByArtistName()` then you should Declare them first.

Like If they contain Application Specific entities and columns then you should declare them first before using them. If it is generalized like `findById()`, `findAll()`, `deleteById()`, then you should use them directly because they're already declared in `CrudRepository`.